# Google Tag Manager, Css Selector trigger not working

Tags: google-tag-manager, eventtrigger, event-tracking

I am trying to catch click events of all `<font>` tags if their parent element has .menuItem class name.

The trigger I made is looking like:

```
Click Classes matches CSS selector .menuItem > font
```

But it is not triggering. What is missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the `Click Classes` that match with a CSS selector, rather it's the `Click Element`. Also, your `.menuItme > font` means that the `font` tag needs to be a direct child of the class `menuItem`.